# Moongoose Nested Objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I need to create a user Schema, in which a user can be either of 3 acceptable options: *admin, teacher, student*. I was thinking of putting it all in one Schema, something like this:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
firstName: String,
lastName: String,
email: String,
username: String,
password: String,
role: {
     type: String, 
     enum: ['admin', 'teacher', 'student'], // only accepts these values
     default: 'student'
},
admin: {
    // some fields related to admin
},
teacher: {
    degree: String,
},
student: {
    indexNumber: String,
}
});
```

Could I nest *admin* and others inside *role*, something like this:

```
role: {
     type: String, 
     enum: ['admin', 'teacher', 'student'], // dozvoljava samo ove vrednosti
     default: 'student',
     admin: {
        // some fields related to admin
    }, ...
}
```

Or this is totally wrong approach and I should make 3 more schemas for admin, teacher and student, and connect them to this userSchema?

Comment: What's the problem with your first approach? I think it's a good approach.

Comment: There is no problem, just I think it's not following good practice, like having fields "admin, teacher, student" in the same "row" as fields "firstName...". Also, for example. if user is student, his fields would be all NULL for the admin and teacher. Not sure if this is good approach, cuz of student still having those fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inherit User schema into three different subtypes using discriminators

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html

Example from mongoose document

```
var options = {discriminatorKey: 'kind'};

var eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({time: Date}, options);
var Event = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);

// ClickedLinkEvent is a special type of Event that has
// a URL.
var ClickedLinkEvent = Event.discriminator('ClickedLink',
  new mongoose.Schema({url: String}, options));
```